# Can we add exceptions to wild card redirects?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I made a domain name change from domaina.com to domainb.com and used a wild card redirect to match all URLs on another domain. I would like to make an exception where the homepage of domaina.com redirects to domainb.com/page.

Is this possible without messing up the functionality of this code (in .htacces of domaina.com) to match the URLs

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank you.

Regards,
Naser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need another RewriteRule.

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://domainb.com/page [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://domainb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a plugin if you're not too familiar with handling `htaccess` commands

I've been using this https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ myself, so easy to manage. It support wildcards & everything!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I only possess the domain without the actual site and won't be able to try the plugin.